Find substrings that contain a certain amount of certain characters
I have a string like GGACATCGCGGTGGATCGAC.
How can I find all substrings that contain, for example, three Gs in any order?
For this string, it would be GCGG or GTGG, or GGACATCG.
Also need to find such substrings for several letters, like, substrings with two Gs and one C (CGAG, GGAC, GGATC, CGG)

You probably need to give example text and expected output.  I just tried (?i)g[^g]*g[^g]*g on your text and it returned GGACATCG and GGTG.

Why does your expected output not also include GACATCGCG, GGTG and GGATCG?

three Gs in any order I don't understand how "in any order" is meaningful here.  Did you really mean "with any amount of other characters in between"?

yes, "with any amount of other characters in between" is correct way to say it

I didn't try to find all possible outputs in that string, there are more, just wanted to show required variability

Sliding Window:

The best way to solve this problem is to write an O(N) algorithm.
If the number of chars are manageable, then it can be tuned reasonably good. If not, you need to write several methods and make your algorithms modular to be easy to debug and maintain.

Code
def _sliding_window(s, char_a, char_b, count_a, count_b):
    res = []
    starts = []

    for i in range(len(s)):
        char = s[i]

        if char in (char_a, char_b):
            starts.append(i)

    for start in starts:
        As, Bs = 0, 0
        temp = ""

        for i in range(start, len(s)):
            char = s[i]

            if char == char_a:
                As += 1
            if char == char_b:
                Bs += 1

            temp += char

            if As == count_a and Bs == count_b:
                res.append(temp)
                break

    return res


s = "GGACATCGCGGTGGATCGCCACGCGACATCGCGGTGGATCGACGGACATCCGCGGTGCGATCCGACGACATGCGCGCG"

print(_sliding_window(s, 'G', 'C', 2, 1), "\n")
print(_sliding_window(s, 'G', 'C', 3, 0), "\n")
print(_sliding_window(s, 'G', 'C', 1, 2), "\n")
print(_sliding_window(s, 'G', 'C', 0, 3), "\n")




Note:

In the above algorithm, we first find the start indices, then we perform sliding window.

Sill has some logic issues that I will leave it to you.

If you don't have much data, you can just use an O(N^ 2) algorithm, which is simple to write.


Prints
['GGAC', 'GCG', 'CGG', 'GGATC', 'GATCG', 'GCG', 'GCG', 'CGG', 'GGATC', 'GATCG', 'GACG', 'CGG', 'GGAC', 'GCG', 'CGG', 'GTGC', 'GCG', 'GACG', 'GACATG', 'GCG', 'GCG', 'GCG'] 

['GGTG', 'GTGG', 'GGTG', 'GTGG', 'GGTG'] 

['GACATC', 'CATCG', 'CGC', 'CGC', 'GCC', 'CACG', 'CGC', 'CGAC', 'GACATC', 'CATCG', 'CGC', 'CGAC', 'GACATC', 'CCG', 'CGC', 'CGATC', 'GATCC', 'CCG', 'CGAC', 'CGAC', 'CATGC', 'CGC', 'CGC'] 

['CCAC', 'CATCC'] 


Regex Pattern
It'd be difficult to write pattern for each and every case. But the way to write a pattern is as follows.

Define a lookahead with what's necessary to be.
Define your patterns one by one for each case and use pipes to join them.

For 3G in any order:
(?=.*G.*G.*G)([G].*?[G].*?[G])

Code
import re

p = r'(?=.*G.*G.*G)([G].*?[G].*?[G])'

s = """
GGACATCGCGGTGGATCGACGGACATCGCGGTGGATCGACGGACATCGCGGTGGATCGAC GACATGCGCGCG. GGACATGCGCGCGGGACATGCGCGCG. GGACATGCGCGCG. 
GCGG or GTGG, or GGACATCG. GCGG or GTGG, or GGACATGCGCGCG. GGACATGCGCGCG. GGACATGCGCGCGGGACATGCGCGCG. GGACATGCGCGCG. 
GCGG or GTGG, or GGACATCG. GCGG or GTGG, or GGACATGCGCGCG. GGACATGCGCGCG. GGACATGCGCGCGGGACATGCGCGCG. GGACATGCGCGCG. 
"""

find_3G = re.findall(p, s)

print(find_3G)

# Note that 'GCG. G' is also part of those found.



Prints

['GGACATCG', 'GGTG', 'GATCGACG', 'GACATCGCG', 'GTGG', 'GACGG', 'GCGG',
'GGATCG', 'GACATGCG', 'GCG. G', 'GACATGCG', 'GCGG', 'GACATGCG', 'GCG.
G', 'GACATGCG', 'GCGG', 'GTGG', 'GGACATCG', 'GCGG', 'GTGG', 'GGACATG',
'GCGCG', 'GGACATG', 'GCGCG', 'GGACATG', 'GCGCG', 'GGACATG', 'GCGCG',
'GGACATG', 'GCGCG', 'GCGG', 'GTGG', 'GGACATCG', 'GCGG', 'GTGG',
'GGACATG', 'GCGCG', 'GGACATG', 'GCGCG', 'GGACATG', 'GCGCG', 'GGACATG',
'GCGCG', 'GGACATG', 'GCGCG']


A naive brute force algorithm for two Gs and one Cs would be the following O(N ^ 2):
def _pattern(s):
    return s.count('G') == 2 and s.count('C') == 1

def _collect(s):
    res = []
    for i in range(len(s)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(s) + 1):
            part = s[i:j]
            if _pattern(part):
                res.append(part)
    return res


s = """
GGACATCGCGGTGGATCGACGGACATCGCGGTGGATCGACGGACATCGCGGTGGATCGAC GACATGCGCGCG. GGACATGCGCGCGGGACATGCGCGCG. GGACATGCGCGCG. 
GCGG or GTGG, or GGACATCG. GCGG or GTGG, or GGACATGCGCGCG. GGACATGCGCGCG. GGACATGCGCGCGGGACATGCGCGCG. GGACATGCGCGCG. 
GCGG or GTGG, or GGACATCG. GCGG or GTGG, or GGACATGCGCGCG. GGACATGCGCGCG. GGACATGCGCGCGGGACATGCGCGCG. GGACATGCGCGCG. 
"""
G, C = 2, 1

print(_collect(s))


Prints

['\nGGAC', '\nGGACA', '\nGGACAT', 'GGAC', 'GGACA', 'GGACAT', 'GCG',
'CGG', 'CGGT', 'TGGATC', 'GGATC', 'GATCG', 'GATCGA', 'GACG', 'ACGG',
'ACGGA', 'CGG', 'CGGA', 'GGAC', 'GGACA', 'GGACAT', 'GCG', 'CGG',
'CGGT', 'TGGATC', 'GGATC', 'GATCG', 'GATCGA', 'GACG', 'ACGG', 'ACGGA',
'CGG', 'CGGA', 'GGAC', 'GGACA', 'GGACAT', 'GCG', 'CGG', 'CGGT',
'TGGATC', 'GGATC', 'GATCG', 'GATCGA', 'GAC G', 'GAC GA', ' GACATG',
'GACATG', 'ATGCG', 'TGCG', 'GCG', 'GCG', 'GCG', 'GCG.', 'GCG. ', 'CG.
G', '. GGAC', '. GGACA', '. GGACAT', ' GGAC', ' GGACA', ' GGACAT',
'GGAC', 'GGACA', 'GGACAT', 'GACATG', 'ATGCG', 'TGCG', 'GCG', 'GCG',
'GCG', 'CGG', 'GGAC', 'GGACA', 'GGACAT', 'GACATG', 'ATGCG', 'TGCG',
'GCG', 'GCG', 'GCG', 'GCG.', 'GCG. ', 'CG. G', '. GGAC', '. GGACA', '.
GGACAT', ' GGAC', ' GGACA', ' GGACAT', 'GGAC', 'GGACA', 'GGACAT',
'GACATG', 'ATGCG', 'TGCG', 'GCG', 'GCG', 'GCG', 'GCG.', 'GCG. ', 'GCG.
\n', 'CG. \nG', 'G. \nGC', '. \nGCG', ' \nGCG', '\nGCG', 'GCG', 'CGG',
'CGG ', 'CGG o', 'CGG or', 'CGG or ', ', or GGAC', ', or GGACA', ', or
GGACAT', ' or GGAC', ' or GGACA', ' or GGACAT', 'or GGAC', 'or GGACA',
'or GGACAT', 'r GGAC', 'r GGACA', 'r GGACAT', ' GGAC', ' GGACA', '
GGACAT', 'GGAC', 'GGACA', 'GGACAT', 'ATCG. G', 'TCG. G', 'CG. G', 'G.
GC', '. GCG', ' GCG', 'GCG', 'CGG', 'CGG ', 'CGG o', 'CGG or', 'CGG or
', ', or GGAC', ', or GGACA', ', or GGACAT', ' or GGAC', ' or GGACA',
' or GGACAT', 'or GGAC', 'or GGACA', 'or GGACAT', 'r GGAC', 'r GGACA',
'r GGACAT', ' GGAC', ' GGACA', ' GGACAT', 'GGAC', 'GGACA', 'GGACAT',
'GACATG', 'ATGCG', 'TGCG', 'GCG', 'GCG', 'GCG', 'GCG.', 'GCG. ', 'CG.
G', '. GGAC', '. GGACA', '. GGACAT', ' GGAC', ' GGACA', ' GGACAT',
'GGAC', 'GGACA', 'GGACAT', 'GACATG', 'ATGCG', 'TGCG', 'GCG', 'GCG',
'GCG', 'GCG.', 'GCG. ', 'CG. G', '. GGAC', '. GGACA', '. GGACAT', '
GGAC', ' GGACA', ' GGACAT', 'GGAC', 'GGACA', 'GGACAT', 'GACATG',
'ATGCG', 'TGCG', 'GCG', 'GCG', 'GCG', 'CGG', 'GGAC', 'GGACA',
'GGACAT', 'GACATG', 'ATGCG', 'TGCG', 'GCG', 'GCG', 'GCG', 'GCG.',
'GCG. ', 'CG. G', '. GGAC', '. GGACA', '. GGACAT', ' GGAC', ' GGACA',
' GGACAT', 'GGAC', 'GGACA', 'GGACAT', 'GACATG', 'ATGCG', 'TGCG',
'GCG', 'GCG', 'GCG', 'GCG.', 'GCG. ', 'GCG. \n', 'CG. \nG', 'G. \nGC',
'. \nGCG', ' \nGCG', '\nGCG', 'GCG', 'CGG', 'CGG ', 'CGG o', 'CGG or',
'CGG or ', ', or GGAC', ', or GGACA', ', or GGACAT', ' or GGAC', ' or
GGACA', ' or GGACAT', 'or GGAC', 'or GGACA', 'or GGACAT', 'r GGAC', 'r
GGACA', 'r GGACAT', ' GGAC', ' GGACA', ' GGACAT', 'GGAC', 'GGACA',
'GGACAT', 'ATCG. G', 'TCG. G', 'CG. G', 'G. GC', '. GCG', ' GCG',
'GCG', 'CGG', 'CGG ', 'CGG o', 'CGG or', 'CGG or ', ', or GGAC', ', or
GGACA', ', or GGACAT', ' or GGAC', ' or GGACA', ' or GGACAT', 'or
GGAC', 'or GGACA', 'or GGACAT', 'r GGAC', 'r GGACA', 'r GGACAT', '
GGAC', ' GGACA', ' GGACAT', 'GGAC', 'GGACA', 'GGACAT', 'GACATG',
'ATGCG', 'TGCG', 'GCG', 'GCG', 'GCG', 'GCG.', 'GCG. ', 'CG. G', '.
GGAC', '. GGACA', '. GGACAT', ' GGAC', ' GGACA', ' GGACAT', 'GGAC',
'GGACA', 'GGACAT', 'GACATG', 'ATGCG', 'TGCG', 'GCG', 'GCG', 'GCG',
'GCG.', 'GCG. ', 'CG. G', '. GGAC', '. GGACA', '. GGACAT', ' GGAC', '
GGACA', ' GGACAT', 'GGAC', 'GGACA', 'GGACAT', 'GACATG', 'ATGCG',
'TGCG', 'GCG', 'GCG', 'GCG', 'CGG', 'GGAC', 'GGACA', 'GGACAT',
'GACATG', 'ATGCG', 'TGCG', 'GCG', 'GCG', 'GCG', 'GCG.', 'GCG. ', 'CG.
G', '. GGAC', '. GGACA', '. GGACAT', ' GGAC', ' GGACA', ' GGACAT',
'GGAC', 'GGACA', 'GGACAT', 'GACATG', 'ATGCG', 'TGCG', 'GCG', 'GCG',
'GCG', 'GCG.', 'GCG. ', 'GCG. \n']


Note

This algorithm can be written in O(N) time complexity. I just wanted to show here that how we'd approach solving the problem.

You can add methods to handle your edge cases.

Algorithms are much flexible, easy to maintain and easy to debug.



In python you can use the regex module to capture overlapping matches. This can simplify your regexes. For 3 G's, you can use:
G[^G]*G[^G]*G

For 2 G's and 1 C, there are three possible combinations as below (where * represents some number of characters which are not G or C):

G*G*C
G*C*G
C*G*G

These can be matched with this regex:
G[^GC]*G[^GC]*C|G[^GC]*C[^GC]*G|C[^GC]*G[^GC]*G

In python
import regex

s = 'GGACATCGCGGTGGATCGAC'
regex.findall(r'G[^G]*G[^G]*G', s, overlapped=True)

regex.findall(r'G[^GC]*G[^GC]*C|G[^GC]*C[^GC]*G|C[^GC]*G[^GC]*G', s, overlapped=True)

Output:
['GGACATCG', 'GACATCGCG', 'GCGG', 'GGTG', 'GTGG', 'GGATCG']
['GGAC', 'GCG', 'CGG', 'GGATC', 'GATCG']


Firstly, you should note that the matching substrings must start and end with the desired letters.
With that constraint, matching substrings containing one letter of an exact number is fairly straightforward by capturing the desired letters with optionally other characters in between:
(?=((?:G[^G]*){2}G))

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/ajXtbq/1
Matching substrings containing two letters of certain exact numbers is quite a bit more involved. It comes down to capturing the desired number of each letter and capturing what follows, and then capturing a substring that is composed of one of the previous captures of the desired letters, followed by characters that that are not that letter, until it is at a point where what follows is one of the previous captures of what follows the other desired letter. Below is an example of capturing substrings with exactly two Gs and one C:
(?=([^C]*C)(.*$))(?=((?:[^G]*G){2})(.*$))(?=(?=[CG])(\1[^C]*(?=\4$)|\3[^G]*(?=\2$)))

Demo (with desired substrings captured in group 5): https://regex101.com/r/uCtCfq/1
For a more generalized solution for any number of letters it's easier and more efficient to use a counter with a sliding window that increments the ending index when the counter is less than the target, or increments the starting index otherwise:
from collections import Counter

def find(s, target_counts):
    target_counts = Counter(target_counts)
    current_counts = Counter()
    start = end = 0
    size = len(s)
    while end < size:
        if current_counts < target_counts:
            if (char := s[end]) in target_counts:
                current_counts[char] += 1
            end += 1
        else:
            if (char := s[start]) in current_counts:
                if current_counts == target_counts:
                    yield s[start: end]
                current_counts[char] -= 1
            start += 1

so that:
print(*find("GGACATCGCGGTGGATCGAC", {'G': 2, 'C': 1}), sep='\n')

outputs:
GGAC
GCG
CGG
GGATC
GATCG

Demo here

Python function to find all such substrings for any counts of letters:
def find_substrings_with_exact_letters(s, letter_counts):
    from collections import Counter

    result = []
    n = len(s)
    total_letters = sum(letter_counts.values())
    
    for i in range(n - total_letters + 1):
        substring = s[i:i + total_letters]
        counts = Counter(substring)
        
        match = all(counts[char] == letter_counts[char] for char in letter_counts)
        
        if match:
            result.append(substring)
    
    return result

# Example usage
s = "GGACATCGCGGTGGATCGCCACGCGACATCGCGGTGGATCGACGGACATCCGCGGTGCGATCCGACGACATGCGCGCG"

letter_counts_3Gs = {'G': 3}
letter_counts_2Gs_1C = {'G': 2, 'C': 1}

substrings_3Gs = find_substrings_with_exact_letters(s, letter_counts_3Gs)
print("Substrings with exactly 3 Gs:", substrings_3Gs)

substrings_2Gs_1C = find_substrings_with_exact_letters(s, letter_counts_2Gs_1C)
print("Substrings with exactly 2 Gs and 1 C:", substrings_2Gs_1C)

modify the letter_counts dictionary to find substrings matching different criteria.
